# PHP Warning: ldap_bind(): Unable to bind to server: Can't contact LDAP server in

Tags: ldap

I've following problem with my php script:
PHP Warning:  ldap_bind(): Unable to bind to server: Can't contact LDAP server in ....

ldap_connect() says "Success" but ldap_bind fails, how to fix that issue?

Thx for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If ldap_bind fails the main reason I can think about is invalid credentials, make sure you're formatting your credentials properly and that the credentials are correct to connect to the LDAP server.

If I were you and if you have shell access try to run `ldapsearch` with the same credentials and see what results are you getting.

Good luck!